# Getting Multiples checks for Github Pull Request using Jenkins

Tags: unit-testing, github, jenkins, github-api, pull-request

I'm working on a project which uses jenkins for ci. I have to validate Github PR and update multiple checks. I'm using the Github Pull Request Builder Plugin.
1. linting the code
2. running unit test
3. code coverage

I want to github display the 3 status checks differently? Despite the 3 builds reporting status to github, github just displays "1 pending check" or "1 status check completed successfully". 
[image]

I didn't find a proper solution for this without being able develop or script for the functionality. Is there any plugin or a way to achieve this.

I want this happen using only one Jenkins job

I have tried writing shell scripts to update the checks in github
its reponse with success message but the PR is not update with the statuses.

```
curl -XPOST -H "Authorization: token XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" https://api.github.com/repos/org/reponame/statuses/$(git rev-parse HEAD) -d '{
    "state": "success",
    "target_url": "${BUILD_URL}",
    "description": "All tests were passed!",
    "context": "jenkins-ci-unit-test"
  }'
```

Response

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
05:15:26                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
05:15:26 
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100  1528  100  1350  100   178   8318   1096 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  8333
05:15:26 {
05:15:26   "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/org/reponame/statuses/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
05:15:26   "id": 333333333,
05:15:26   "state": "success",
05:15:26   "description": "All tests were passed!",
05:15:26   "target_url": "http://xxx.xxxxx.com/job/job1",
05:15:26   "context": "jenkins-ci-unit-test",
05:15:26   "created_at": "2016-11-29T10:15:26Z",
05:15:26   "updated_at": "2016-11-29T10:15:26Z",
05:15:26   "creator": {
05:15:26    .......
05:15:26   }
05:15:26 }
```

[image: Current check in PR]

Comment: It's not exactly clear to me what you're trying to achieve here. Could you perhaps supply a screenshot of what your current pull request status checks look like?

Comment: It would be easier with three jobs that shared the workspace. You can write a script that returns three status checks after each check via cURL. Just make context different. https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/#create-a-status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commit hash you use to update the check is wrong. It should be the last current commit of the PR.. You need to get the correct commit hash by calling the following github API end point
https://api.github.com/repos/orgname/reponame/pulls/prno

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
git rev-list --max-count=2 HEAD | tail -n 1
```

instead of

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

So it takes the previous commit value